# Using ActionListener and KeyListener in same class

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, keylistener

Actually I am coding a program where I both need to detect actions as well as key presses on the Keyboard. How can I implement both the ActionListener and KeyListener in the same class? If I cannot, please suggest an alternative way to code the same situation. I will be really grateful to everyone for an answer.

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: Yes i have tried a lot many number of times

Comment: Just for future reference, it is best practice on SO to a) show the (relevant) code in order to show your attempt as well as to enable people to reproduce the issue, b) explain exactly *what* doesn't work ("I tried it didn't work" doesn't tell us anything). Check http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Without showing us your work, you force folks to give the same answers that have been given so many times for the same types of questions.

Answer (score 2):

Just let them implement your interfaces:

```
public class MyClass implements KeyListener, ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){/** do something **/}

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){/** do something different **/}

}
```

(untested)

The `KeyListener` class needs a bunch of other Methods, but i guess your IDE will tell you...

Comment: It doesn't work this way... It will show error that since MyClass is not abstract, it does not Override methods of KeyListener...

Comment: As i told you, you need to implement all methods in KeyListener-class. So obviously, yes. Override all Methods and you are ready to go.

Comment: or you can use KeyAdapter

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this,

```
public class example implements ActionListener, KeyListener { }
```